# Pandas calculating percentage of employed individuals grouped by month and year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file that contains 3 columns, year: 'HRYEAR4', month: 'HRMONTH', and employment status at the time: 'PEMPLR_1'. The employment status is a dummy taking value 1 if employed and 0 otherwise.

I want to calculate the percentage of individuals who are employed within a given month, at the year.

I have data from jan. 2018 - apr. 2020 in the data frame df_CPS:

```
             HRMONTH    HRYEAR4    PEMLR_1
0            1          2018       1        
1            1          2018       1  
2            1          2018       1
3            1          2018       0
4            1          2018       0
...         ...          ...      ...
1498116      4          2020       1
1498117      4          2020       1
1498118      4          2020       0
1498119      4          2020       1
1498120      4          2020       1
```

I can get the amount of individuals who are employed grouped by year and month and the total number of individuals in the dataset grouped by year and month:

```
# Individuals who have answered PEMLR = 1 (employed) in a given month, year
df_CPS.groupby(['HRYEAR4', 'HRMONTH']).agg({'PEMLR_1': 'sum'})

# Individuals in total in a given month, year
df_CPS.groupby(['HRYEAR4', 'HRMONTH']).size()
```

But, how can i calculate the percentage of individuals who are employed grouped by month and year?
and add it to the original data set?

I would like to end up with:

```
             HRMONTH    HRYEAR4    PEMLR_1    PEMLR_PCT
0            1          2018       1          90.1       
1            1          2018       1          90.1  
2            1          2018       1          90.1
3            1          2018       0          90.1
4            1          2018       0          90.1
...         ...          ...      ...        ...
1498116      4          2020       1          73.8
1498117      4          2020       1          73.8
1498118      4          2020       0          73.8
1498119      4          2020       1          73.8
1498120      4          2020       1          73.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_CPS.groupby(['HRYEAR4', 'HRMONTH']).agg({'PEMLR_1': 'mean'})
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot! and how do i get it back into the original dataframe ? (as shown in the question)